# Loading bootstrap css after page load

Tags: css, asynchronous, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-pagespeed

Google PageSpeed insights is suggesting to remove render blocking css:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Achieving this means picking out enough pieces from the bootstrap style rules to render above the fold content and then to link the bootstrap css file after the page has loaded.

That's a lot of work, but doable (I suppose).

However, when linking the bootstrap css after page load, all of the in-line overrides to the bootstrap rules are lost.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

David

Comment: You may want a custom download: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. You can choose which features you need and disable the other ones.

Comment: Using the full css file over an established cdn is a much better solution because it is extremely likely that the user already has this file on their machine (cache).  A customized version of bootstrap means the user will have to download it (unecessarily).  As well, even customizing bootstrap yields a file that is far too large to include as inline css and hence, does not solve the problem (render-blocking)

Answer (score 4):

I would load bootstrap from the CDN using JS after the page content, then use this online tool to extract the critical path CSS:
https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/
(or you can use the same tool locally with Node or PhantomJS: https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse)

The extracted CSS would be minimized and placed in your header.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for this tip, I was doing it by hand, great tool.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in the end which I want to share, should someone else need it.

Firstly I downloaded a customized build of the bootstrap css as AmacB suggested above.
I copied the css into excel, with each rule having 1 line.
In the next column I put an **x** beside each rule and in the 3rd column, I wrote a formula to show the rule if there was an **x** and to not show the rule if there was no **x**. I then copied the the 3rd column and uploaded it to my site as a css file.

It worked of course, but the Css was 32kbytes.  Too much to inline.

So I started looking at each rule to decide if I needed it for above the fold content.
Where I felt a rule was not needed, I deleted the **x**, saved the 3rd column, uploaded and checked how it worked.
This process took several hours, but finally I got the css down to just those rules I needed for above the fold.
The resulting file had about 80 rules.

Then, in my **php** file, in the page header I added:

```
$TheCSS=file_get_contents('/css/bootstrap-reduced.css');
echo '<style>'.$TheCSS.'</style>';
```

My score on Pagespeed Insights is now **99/100**.

The solution adds 4kb to every page which is counter productive.
So... After the page is loaded, in jquery I make a link to the bootstrap cdn and on the next page load, I use that link instead of inserting inline css.

**Wrote VBA code to simplify the process:**

```
Sub SaveAsTextFile()
TheFileName = "bootstrap-atf.css"
ThePath = "C:\Users\MyFolder\"
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp"
Sheets("Temp").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Temp").Columns("A").Select
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Set Rng = Selection
Open ThePath & TheFileName For Output As #1
For i = 1 To LastRow
 cellValue = Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
 If cellValue <> "" Then Print #1, cellValue
Next i
Close #1
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
End Sub
```

Put a checkmark beside a bunch of rules in the excel sheet, hit the "Save CSS" button (you can add a button to the excel sheet) and the rules are saved as a css file called bootstrap-atf.css (atf=above the fold)

Greatly simplfies the trial and error process.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the use of CDNs for Bootstrap and JS, if you are in need of performance. In your case get a copy of bootstrap [getbootstrap.com/getting-started/](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.6/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist.zip) and integrate it in your css directories.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp    "Many users already have downloaded Bootstrap from MaxCDN when visiting another site. As a result, it will be loaded from cache when they visit your site, which leads to faster loading time. Also, most CDN's will make sure that once a user requests a file from it, it will be served from the server closest to them, which also leads to faster loading time."

Comment: @Cymro's correct. Adding to what's already been said, using CDNs also mean that your server will be doing some bandwidth savings. Bootstrap adds a considerable amount to load - its own css, fonts, js and jQuery as a dependency. All this adds up to more than 200kB (~60kB gzipped). You can save on this transfer per visit, thanks to CDNs

Comment: The answer is voted down, but I'd say it really depends on the situation: Have users cached the Bootstrap CSS file already? Do you have a CDN yourself? Can you put the CSS file on the same host name, to avoid the overhead of an extra SSL connection? etc.

Comment: If you are improving Google PageSpeed Insights score, then @snowow78 answer is correct -  Google PageSpeed Insights is also giving better score when loading resources from the project instead of CDN.